# MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json

Estoy teniendo un error que no sé cómo solucionar. El error es el siguiente:

> MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended

Creo que tiene que ver con el funcionamiento asíncrono, pero he probado de todo con `await` y `then` y no consigo solucionarlo.

Tengo una ruta post:

```javascript
router.post('/users/getuser', async (req, res) =>
{

    const user = await userQueries.getUserById(req.body.id)
    res.json(user);

});
```

Que llama al método `userQueries.getUserById(id)`, el cual es el siguiente:

```javascript
const getUserById = async (id) =>
{
    await connection.connect();
    let message;
    await User.findById(id).then((done, err) =>
    {
        if (err)
        {
            message = "An error has ocurred";
        } else
        {
            console.log(done);
            message = "User " + done + " deleted";
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    });
        
    return message;
    
};
```

Este método simplemente busca por `id` a un usuario y devuelve la información.

No sé porque recibo el error que comento al principio. ¿Veis algún fallo?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Ya que estas usando `await` aprovecha y hace  `connection.disconnect();` justo antes del `return message;`

Comment: ese uso de `await` con `then` es "raro"... si disconnect es una funcion asincrona, podrías entonces hacer `return connection.disconnect();`

Comment: @Marcos Buenas Marcos, el error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: @Pipe Buenas, el error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: Estás seguro que el error lo bota esta funcion? no se estárá ejecutando algo mas que esté causando el error? a que linea del código te manda el callstack?

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que desde el servidor llamaba dos veces seguida a la misma función(la cual llama a esta). Entonces se ejecutaba dos veces y aparecía el error. Fallo tonto mío. ¡Gracias por la ayuda!